# I want to use the Instagram API to retrieve instagram_business_account, but some accounts work well, others don't, and I'm having trouble

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to use the Instagram Graph API to obtain insights and other information, but I'm puzzled by some accounts that can and cannot retrieve instagram_business_account. When I execute the following URL to obtain instagram_business_account, some accounts return JSON with instagram_business_account included, while others return JSON without instagram_business_account.

The URI I'm executing:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{page-id}?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token={access_token}
```

What is the difference between accounts that can retrieve instagram_business_account and those that cannot?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#requirements: _"The instagram_business_account field requires a User access token from a User who is able to perform appropriate tasks on the Page. Refer to the Instagram Graph API's Page reference for more information."_

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/page explains which additional permission you might need, if the user had their role on the page granted via the business manager.

Comment: And what tasks the user must be allowed to perform on the page, to be able to _get_ certain permissions granted & working, ist listed here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview#tasks